# Importing vendor css when using webpack + css components

Tags: css, webpack, css-modules

I'm trying to use things like **font-awesome** and **foundation** with React and css modules but I can't figure it out how to import them into my project properly.

Note that I'm using `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` and `ExtractTextPlugin` to get a single css file.

Somewhere in the top-level component's css file I'd like to be able to just do `@import 'font-awesome';` but how can I do it so that the file will be treated as-is and the classes won't end up localised to `font_awesome__fa-check` and such?

This is my webpack config:

```
var paths = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, './app/'),
  dist: path.join(__dirname, './dist/'),
  external: path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/'),
}
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    site: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5000',
      'webpack/hot/dev-server',
      path.join(paths.app, '/index.js'),
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: paths.dist,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'scripts/[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js'],
    root: paths.app,
    alias: {
      'font-awesome.css': path.join(paths.external, '/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]&importLoaders=1', 'postcss-loader')
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: [
    require('autoprefixer-core'),
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles/[name].[chunkhash].css", {allChunks: true}),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(paths.app, '/site.html'),
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      chunks: ['site']
    }),
  ]
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could leverage include / exclude option when configuring loaders.

E.g. given that all of your custom css is somewhere in the `/app/` directory, while foundation and font-awesome are not.

```
...
module: {
    loaders: [

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]&importLoaders=1', 'postcss-loader'),
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader!css-loader'),
        exclude: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
      }
    ]
},
```

Another option is to use different extension for the files that use css-modules syntax. You could use `.mcss`.

```
...
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.mcss$/,
        loader: 'css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]&importLoaders=1'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader')
      }
    ],
    postLoaders: [
        {
            test: /\.(css|mcss)$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader')
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: Great! That actually works. Note that I have to require the external css from the js though. Importing it from a css module will still make it all local. Thanks

Comment: @syko I ended up using a different extension for files with css-modules syntax in my projects. see my updated answer

Comment: @Shvetusya your a life saver. BTW extract plugins should now have fallback.
```
      { test: /\.css$/, include: [ resolve('./src/styles'), /node_modules/], use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: [ 'css-loader' ] }) },
```